# mongoid apparently leaking when looping on several records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I got a User model that embeds many notifications and I have to loop through the users collection and them loop through each notification to delete it or not.

First I got cursor timeout errors and then went by using this step method (that I read somewhere) and "only" criteria. My actual loop code is like this:

```
per_batch = 20
users_targeted = User.only(:notifications, :slug).where(:notifications_count.gt => 40).asc(:slug)
0.step(users_targeted.count, per_batch) do |offset|
  users_targeted.limit(per_batch).skip(offset).each do |user|
    user.notifications.only(:_id).read.desc(:updated_at).skip(40).each do |n|
      n.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

- I'm using mongoid 2.4.8
- User collection is ~ 8k
- each user has up to 300 notifications

Now, when the loop is on 3k-4k users, Heroku dyno's memory goes beyond its limit and the loop stops.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem? I have to do a lot of loops like this one so this has been kind of a hassle for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is a memory leak, but you can handle your memory issue and also do the stuff a lot quicker by not iterating over the user collection and try to remove the notifications using mass updates. You should use a combination of [$pop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pop/) and [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/).

```
users = User.where(:notifications_count.gt => 40)
while users.count > 0
  User.collection.update(users.selector, 
                         {"$inc" => {notifications_count: -1}, "$pop" => {notifications: 1}} ,
                         multi: true, safe: true)
end
```